# How to use uiwebview inside a cell of a tableview and avoid load pages on top of reuses cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiwebview

I have a tableview and each cell has a webview.On each webview i load a different embed video from youtube.

```
CardCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CardCell"];
NSString *fullURL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"https://youtube.com/embed/%@?",videoID];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];

NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[cell.videoView loadRequest:requestObj];
cell.videoView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
```

My problem is that every time i scroll the table, because of reusing the cells, on webview it shows the previous video and after a sec it shows the correct one.

I tried to use this: https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper
but it creates every time a different web view and that makes the scrolling REALLY slow and not smooth at all.

Any solutions?
`

Answer (score 0):

You surely can use the youtube ios player library.

1. Create a custom cell and add in the cell a `UIView`.
2. Change the `UIView` class to be a `YTPlayerView` subclass
3. Create an outlet for the `YTPlayerView` to your custom cell subclass
4. In the prepareForReuse, clear the previous video:

   ```
   - (void)prepareForReuse {
       [super prepareForReuse];

       _youTubePlayer.hidden = YES;
       [_youTubePlayer stopVideo];
       [_youTubePlayer clearVideo];
       }
   ```

In the above snippet the `_youTubePlayer` is the outLet to the `YTPlayerView`

You can also set a delegate for the `YTPlayerViewDelegate` and depending on the video status, update your cell..

Comment: this is what happening when i use YTPlayerView https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/8028679/10536869/ede4b95e-73f6-11e5-9e4a-8d70fe4c27b1.png https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/8028679/10537232/0eaf84fa-73f9-11e5-9a59-2482f504d6fe.png

Comment: What exactly is happening ?